# Unable to write file to path in Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I am trying to write string by creating a file temporarily within the view folder of the solution dynamically. 
I get the currentpath as below and append further to the path I needed :

```cs
         string tempPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Views\\" + guid + "_" + fileName + 
         ".cshtml";
         File.WriteAllText(tempPath, data);
```

This is working perfectly fine locally. But not where the application is hosted. I want to write the file only under the subfolder Views, but its not happening. Its failing to write to the file in the hosted app.

I have tried other options like `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location` - which goes to bin/debug --- which is not going to reach Views folder. How should I fix this to get the path as required:

`C:\Users\....\Services\A.B.C\A.B.C.API\Views\91c914d6-f551-4eea-97de-d8f842d1692e_File_NAME.cshtml`

Comment: "Fails" usually comes with more information, like "invalid path" or "no access rights".
Try to get more details on the error message. You have to check if you,or your application, has access-rights to this given path. The administrator could have set your path to "readonly" or "no right at all".

Comment: There's *no* valid reason for an application to write into the `Views` folder. This just *begs* for script injection attacks. If you want to modify what a view renders based on some data or condition, use the proper conditional code

Comment: What are you trying to do? Writing in `Views` at runtime isn't the solution

Comment: I am trying to write the .cshtml template I get from database and update some values inside it and use that file to download.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Is there any reference to see - rendering .cshtml template from the local path? How do I change my Viewengine to refer to the file in the local folder and not under views.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what happened when the write fails.

If an exception thrown, you probably got the explanation in the message. If it is a missing NTFS right, just add it.

If nothing happened and the execution continue, you probably write in the wrong folder: diplay the value returned by Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() on the console.
If you cannot modify the source code, monitor the files with a tool like procmon (Microsoft sysinternals tool) to see where the file is written.

Tell us more about the behavior to get mor help.

Comment: Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() works fine, but not on the hosted place. Its linux platform where it is hosted. So File.WriteAllText(tempPath, data) is failing.